# How to forcefully remove status bar icon?

Tags: icon, ios

I had this app called [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/) for working environment communication.

However, the status bar icon of this app is so ugly that I avoid look at it every time when I glimpsing over status bar.

The worst thing is there is no option for hide it in the settings. Is there anyway that I can forcefully remove it?

Comment: Have you tried pressing cmd + dragging the icon out of the bar?

Comment: @2DD8847 Yes, I have, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the options within Spark. Apps often have an checkbox to hide icon from status bar.

Comment: As Spark is an open source project, consider logging a bug or requesting the ability to turn off the status bar icon. It may already be possible but poorly documented.

Comment: @Rob It doesn't have this option

Comment: @GrahamMiln This app is really a mess, I only open it because I need it during work. Bartender is the best option, despite it costs $15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**Bartender**](http://macbartender.com/). This lets you hide (as well as re-arrange) menu bar items, as well as providing a secondary menu bar so that you can hide icons from the main bar but still have access to them on a keyboard shortcut or menu bar item.

[image]

Comment: Looks good, however, it costs $15. Do you have any cheaper or free alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [Broomstick](http://www.zibity.com/broomstick). It's free and can hide any app icon in the menubar.

Comment: Please note it's not officially compatible with Mavericks.

Comment: Broomstick also doesn't support the app that I want to hide, and I need to submit a request for hide that app.